# Returned error: Sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx when running offline transaction with web3

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

I'm trying to run the javascript following code to make a transaction to a contract function offline against a Ganache blockchain but I get the following error:
"Error: Returned error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 1 and the sender's account only has: 0"

(privateKey and publicKey are a Ganache account public/private keys).

I don't know why the script cannot figure out the sender account balance. Any idea?

Many thanks.

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
  from: publicKey,
});
var data = myContract.methods.pickWinner().encodeABI();

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
  data,
  gas: 1,
  gasPrice: 1
}, privateKey)
.then((res) => {

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(res.rawTransaction, function(err, hash) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log(hash);
  });

});
```

Comment: try to specify the account sending the transaction, and see if it works

Comment: Specifying it where?

Comment: where you aded the gas and gasPrice attributes

Comment: It's not helping unfortunately. And it looks like the signTransaction method is not expecting any 'from' field (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction). Many thanks for trying though.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I'm running into the same issue without any luck so far.

Comment: Nope unfortunately. Have switched to working on something else.

Comment: I had been testing with Ganache and had hard-coded the private key given but then restarted the server so the key wouldn't work as it was regenerated.

Answer (score 1):

There was a known issue pertaining sendRawTransaction and ganache-cli v6.1.5. Upgrading to v6.1.6 should fix your issue. If you're using the GUI then upgrade to 1.2.1 which contains the aforementioned fix (https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases/tag/v1.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error. I was able to solve it by changing the mnemonic in my truffle-config.js to match the mnemonic given by Ganache CLI.

Because each time you run Ganache, the mnemonic changes. but you have to remember to change it in your config file to access the funds in the correct account

Comment: Hello, Could you please elaborate this a little bit more??