# How to solve "sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and the sender's account only has: 0"?

Tags: testing, ethers.js, hardhat

I found a similar answer for this question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41991/returned-error-sender-doesnt-have-enough-funds-to-send-tx-when-running-offline), but I am using hardhat and ethers for my testing.

I am just sending erc20 to my contract and here is my test file:

```
it("Transferring Tokens to myContract",async function(){

      // const WETHTransferAmount10 = parseUnits("10", 18);
      const WETHTransferAmount10 = 10;

      console.log("myContract WETH Balance before Transfer: ",formatUnits(await WETHLocalContract.balanceOf(FactoryContract.address)));

      console.log("WETHAddress Eth Balance: ",formatUnits(await ethers.provider.getBalance(WETHcontractAddress)));

      // Approving FactoryContract with tokens
      await WETHLocalContract.connect(WETHSigner);
      await WETHLocalContract.approve(FactoryContract.address,WETHTransferAmount10);

      
      // await WETHSigner.sendTransaction(await WETHLocalContract.approve(FactoryContract.address,WETHTransferAmount10));
      
      // console.log("ALLowance is: ", formatUnits(await WETHLocalContract.allowance(WETHSigner.address,FactoryContract.address)));

      // Transferring the token
      console.log("Balance of WETH owner in WETH: ", formatUnits(await WETHLocalContract.balanceOf(WETHSigner.address)));
      await FactoryContract.connect(WETHSigner).stakeToken(WETHcontractAddress,WETHTransferAmount10)
```

stakeToken function has just this line for now

```
ERC20Interface(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
```

Comment: give the ethereum account  that is sending transaction some funds

Comment: It already have enough balance: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103477/how-to-solve-sender-doesnt-have-enough-funds-to-send-tx-the-upfront-cost-is?noredirect=1#comment126748_103478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much is your balance before sending the transaction. the error says that you don't have enough balance to pay for the transaction. also you should know that the balance must be equal to the balance you are setting as maximum.

so in your transaction, if you are setting a 20GWei price and 10GWei of gas Amount you will need to have in balance the equivalent of 200GWei (price * amount ) as balance before even sending the transaction.

in your case check hardHat's default config of price and amount set for all transactions.

Also, this error is thrown before the transaction is sent to the network, so it has nothing to do with the blockchain itself.

Comment: I have enough balance:
```WETHHolder Eth Balance:  6936711.957134258047662892
Balance of WETH owner in WETH:  123577.577905175390133903
```

Comment: How does the staking in your contract works? if the contract wallet doesn't have enough balance and it tries to make a transaction it will error out the same way you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my hardhat package and tried the main net forking block number which resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error while doing a course, who many people might be doing, I was fixing many things and forgot to update the address and private keys, pls do check those after doing changes in the code, it might be the reason for 0 funds while using ganache.

Comment: I'm learning a course on egghead, and face the same problem. Then I realize that I fogot one step: "Click to Grab funds from the faucet". I clicked and I'm now able to call SetPurpose

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mnemonic variable in truffle.js file matches the one from your local blockchain, Ganache.

Comment: Sir, could you please tell me a little bit more how to do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you send a transaction, you have to have enough eth to pay for the max possible gas cost of a tx. That is, the gasLimit * gasPrice value. So if the gas limit is huge, you'll need much more ETH, even if then the actual gas used is very small compared to the set gas limit.

So my guess is that your tx is setting a large gas limit, for some reason. If that's the case, you should figure out why that's happening.

I'm tentatively closing this, but please re-open if you still think the problem is on Hardhat's side.